# How can I prove that this function is bounded using the given 2 hints?

Tags: functions

How can I prove that this function is bounded using the given 2 hints?
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1},$$

**Hints:**

1. $(x + 1)^2 \geq 0.$
2. $(x - 1)^2 \geq 0.$

thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused by those hints... I do not think they are true? $1-(x^2+2x+1) \ge 0$ is only true for $0\ge x \ge -2$

Comment: @HarryAlli The hints most likely mean $Q1: (x+1)^2\ldots$, not $1-(x+1)^2$.

Comment: @Intuition Velut Luna's answer explains how to do it with the hints but it should be fairly intuitive, in my opinion. Clearly the function's got no vertical asymptotes for real $x$, since $x^2+1>0$. But as $x\to\pm\infty$, the denominator is much larger, so $f\to0$, so $f$ is finite for all real $x$, which means it's bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(x+1)^2 \ge 0 \iff x^2+1 \ge -2x$$
$$(x-1)^2 \ge 0 \iff x^2+1 \ge 2x$$
Therefore
$$x^2+1 \ge 2|x|$$

$$\left|\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right| = \frac{|x|}{x^2+1} \le \frac{|x|}{2|x|} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Answer (score 3):

Your example is not difficult. Let me give you a more general approach. Consider

$$y=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx^2+ex+f},$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are constants. To find the range of the function, rearrange the equation

$$(a-dy)x^2+(b-ey)x+(c-fy)=0.$$

If $y$ is in the range of the fractional quadratic function, the discriminant is nonnegative. So

$$\Delta=(b-ey)^2-4(a-dy)(c-fy)\geq 0,$$

which is a quadratic inequality for $y$. In your case $a=0, b=1, c=0, d=1, e=0, f=1$, so the inequality reduces to

$$1-4y^2\geq 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad-\frac{1}{2}\leq y\leq\frac{1}{2},$$

which is the range of the function $x/(x^2+1)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.